# "Unable to cast object of System.Byte[] to ActiveDs.IADsSecurityDescriptor"

Tags: c#, asp.net, openldap

My problem is that I am using `LDAPconnection` class and connecting over SSL. I manage to get nTSecurityDescriptor value but now getting error

> "Unable to cast object of System.Byte[] to ActiveDs.IADsSecurityDescriptor"

I am using code like this

```
SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
IADsSecurityDescriptor sd = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)response.Entries[0].Attributes["nTSecurityDescriptor"][0];
```

Is there any error or some other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

At last I find the answer of my question. This class convert the byte[] to valid security decriptor comobject.

```
ActiveDs.ADsSecurityUtility secUtility = new ActiveDs.ADsSecurityUtility();
ActiveDs.IADsSecurityDescriptor sd = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)secUtility.ConvertSecurityDescriptor((byte[])attribute[0], (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_RAW, (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID);
```