# Property value returned by DirectorySearcher and SearchResponse are of different type System._comobject and Byte array

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am working on a website to manage active directory. I want to check that whether user has permission to change password or not. So I have to find **"ntSecurityDescriptor"** property value after that I have to cast it into IADsSecurityDescriptor.

Now if I use DirectorySearcher class then property value is of type **System._ComObject** and easily casted to **IADsSecurityDescriptor**. But when I use LdapConnection and SearchResponse I get property value of type.

```
byte[] array which is unale to cast to IADsSecityDescriptor.
```

I am getting error

```
Unable to cast System.Byte[] to IADsSecurityDescriptor
```

Is there some problem with SearchResponse or I have use some kind of casting technique to achieve this? I have some problem to use DirectoryEntry class so I can only use LdapConnction class.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to cast object of System.Byte\[\] to ActiveDs.IADsSecurityDescriptor"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245822/unable-to-cast-object-of-system-byte-to-activeds-iadssecuritydescriptor)

Comment: @jbl Hi jbl Let me know if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I find the answer of my question. This class convert the byte[] to valid security decriptor comobject.

```
ActiveDs.ADsSecurityUtility secUtility = new ActiveDs.ADsSecurityUtility();
ActiveDs.IADsSecurityDescriptor sd = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)secUtility.ConvertSecurityDescriptor((byte[])attribute[0], (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_RAW, (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your effort in trying to use the DirectoryEntry method. 
You will have **very** hard times trying to manipulate AD objects with LdapConnection.

If you want to continue the Ldap way, after a quick search, I would give a try to the native (this word says it all) autorization functions. There seems to be interesting things in there, like :

ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
 C# syntax

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern bool ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(string StringSecurityDescriptor, uint StringSDRevision, ref IntPtr SecurityDescriptor, IntPtr SecurityDescriptorSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its too urgent for me that's why I entered multiple questions. I find RawSecurityDescriptor class which accepts byte[] in its constructor and I get object which have properties like  SecurityDescriptor comobject. but I am not able to cast it to IADsSecurityDescriptor.